# Is there a way to access skirmish without being in queue for a match?

Tags: overwatch

I want to test some graphic settings (but this question could also apply if you want to do some warmup before going into competitive) and I'm looking for a way to get into skirmish to test my settings in a 'real' match before going into matchmaking (to see if I get constant FPS).

So is there a way to get into Skirmish mode, without being in queue for a match?

Comment: +1 for this question! I'd love to be able to just skirmish to screw around with characters I'm not proficient in. Sometimes I just like skirmish because you know no one gives a #@*% (see when enemies just wave at each other, or bounce around without shooting, or shoot everywhere EXCEPT each other -- basically anything other than murder on sight, which is what most other matches are)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two ways to skirmish:

1. Is done through the Custom Game, where you can play by yourself or with your friends.

[image]

2. The other is through the general settings, turning on "Skirmish while you wait" puts you in a skirmish game with your party, while waiting to be matched in a quick/competative/brawl game.

Still, to test in an actual, real match enviornment your best bet is either quick play or custom game against AI (6V6) to get the actual projectiles going and potentially hurting your FPS

Comment: But any way to jump into the skirmishes with other players? Those made when you wait for a game? This will make me a game with only me/invited in it?

Comment: Thats in the general settings "skirmish while you wait" or something like that.

Comment: @ИвоНедев except that doesn't accomplish what the asker wanted. He doesn't want to skirmish _while he waits_, he wants to skirmish _by itself_, without being queued for another match type.

Comment: @DoktorJ There are two types of skirmishes, one explained in my answer and one explained in the comment.

Comment: But you can't just skirmish with random players through either method -- only with friends or AI (or by yourself). Additionally, I don't believe custom games allow you to disable objectives (objectives are disabled in an actual skirmish, so it's basically team deathmatch, or team hellomatch as the case may sometimes be)